# unresolved classes from installed plugin

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I am developing a custom plugin where is make use of groovys HTTPbuilder
everything works fine when i run the plugin independently during tests(both manual and integration tests)
However when i package and install the plugin in another app i get the following errors when running the app

> unable to resolve class groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
>   unable to resolve class groovyx.net.http.ContentType

I guess this has to do with dependency resolution but i do not know exactly what and why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you did not specify to the plugin to include HTTPBuilder when it is deployed. In BuildConfig.groovy you can specify your plugins like so:

```
dependencies {
    // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or         
    build : 'lib/http-builder.jar' //If you are manually including the http builder jar
}
plugins {
    build: ':joda-time:1.1'
    test ':fixtures:1.0.RC1.SNAPSHOT',
    ':spock:0.4-groovy-1.7-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

[Here is a good link](http://www.nslms.com/2011/01/03/grails-plugin-dependencies/)

Comment: Thanks thought that the plugin automatically resolves the dependencies needed since it worker while only running the plugins